# Angular JS- Dynamic anchor tag ng-click not working after compile

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to add dynamically  created anchor tag in HTML for this purpose I
 have used below code in JS :

```
var tabList = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a ng-click="getActiveTag()">Test</a>');
var temp = $compile(tabList)($scope); 
$scope.tabList = temp[0];
```

and on html side I have used :

```
<p ng-bind-html="tabList"></p>
```

but ng-click not working :( ..any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you give us a plunker/fiddle ?

Comment: I think you could use a directive instead of ng-bind-html

Comment: you have to manually insert that $compiled dom, not with ng-bind-html.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .appendTo function. Adding sample code.

```
<body>
<p id="appendHere"></p>
</body>

.js
angular.module("testApp",[]).controller("testContoller", function($scope, $compile)
{
$scope.tabList = '<a ng-click="getActiveTag()">Test</a>';
$compile($scope.tabList)($scope).appendTo(angular.element("#appendHere")); 
//$scope.tabList = temp[0];
});

$scope.getActiveTag = function()
{
    alert('calling anchor click');
}
```

This needs jquery loaded first before angular library.

Edited

```
var testVar = angular.element('<a ng-click="getActiveTag()">Test</a>');
$compile(testVar)($scope).appendTo(angular.element("#appendHere"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your suggestions .I found the solution, 
I have removed ng-bind-html and place already compiled DOM as suggested by "YOU".And after studying thoroughly  [Angularjs-compiler](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler), follow the steps below and it works :)

```
// Step 1: parse HTML into DOM element
var template = angular.element(''<a ng-click="getActiveTag()">Test</a>'');
// Step 2: compile the template
var linkFn = $compile(template);
// Step 3: link the compiled template with the scope.
var element = linkFn($scope);
// Step 4: Append to DOM (optional)
$("#content").append(element);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i mentioned in my answer dude...In this solution you are extending number of coding line which I believe you should look into it..

Anyway happy coding...!!! :)

Comment: Thanks Akash, I have tried your solution only thing changed is first  parse HTML into DOM element and then pass this dom element to $compile "$compile(template) " instead of passing directly  $scope element "$compile($scope.tabList)".

Comment: Dude..I dont know what you are referring to..If you are concerning $scope element then I would say you can still declare it as a normal variable.. See my edition. Apart from this you have static anchor element which you need to compile and for that I dont think you need to parse that HTML into DOM element with angular.element function.

Answer (score 0):

Try ngHref in your HTML instead:

```
<p>
  <a ng-href="getActiveTag()">Test</a>
</p>
```